# resize / drag usercontrol at runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

How can I resize / drag a usercontrol in silverlight 4 at runtime through a resizehandle in the bottomright corner for example? As a beginner I have no idea how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found exactly what I was looking for. I was using a childwindow but it blocked interaction with parent so I thought I had to create a usercontrol and built in resize function and drag function and stuff.

This guy took the childwindow and refactored it for non-modal use:

- http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/05/10/silverlight-childwindow-non-modal-refactor.aspx
- latest build here: http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/